# Custom search form

Tags: 7, search

I am currently printing the search from like this:

```
$block = module_invoke('search', 'block_view', 'search');
print render($block);
```

Wich generates:

```
<form action="/sescam/" method="post" id="search-block-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div>
        <div class="container-inline">
             <h2 class="element-invisible">Search form</h2>

            <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-search-block-form">
                <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-search-block-form--2">Search</label>
                <input title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." type="text" id="edit-search-block-form--2" name="search_block_form" value="" size="15" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-actions">
                <input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Search" class="form-submit" />
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-NhLKDp33kDMoJjHqw6gDFJw_A_Kp7Dhvrt_w0V-jk6U" />
            <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="e9aNbw3gz2mWvZUSdjl54aXTlesQsNkn7cGSXVMpoWI" />
            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="search_block_form" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The thing is that I would like to customize a little bit this html output,

How can I Do so?

-EDIT-

I tried to add this to my template.php

```
function my_theme_form_search_form_alter (& $form, & $form_state)
{
  print_r($form);
  print_r($form_state);
}
```

The thing is that those `print_r` won't output anything,

Anhy idea?

thanks!

Comment: The ID is `search_block_form`, so...

Comment: Hi @Clive Sorry but I am not familiar with Drupal yet, what do you mean? thanks ( If you mean I can customize the looks by selecting it with css, it's not really what I am looking for, I would like to customize the whole output..)

Comment: Not what I meant, I've put an answer in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're implementing [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7), to which you're providing `search_form` as the ID - if you look at the markup for the form you can see the ID should be `search_block_form`, so your function should be:

```
function MYTHEME_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Make changes
}
```

To find out the ID of a form, you can temporarily implement the standard `hook_form_alter()`, and put the ID out to the screen:

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  drupal_set_message($form_id);
}
```

Just as an aside, don't rely on seeing anything from `print_r()` - because of output buffering you may or may not see it. To debug Drupal, install the [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel), and use the `dpm()` function to inspect vars.

Comment: Hi again, I see.. Thing is I can play with the attributes and all that, but How should I rewrite the output? Shall I copy the original one?

Comment: Depends entirely on what you want to change - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106894/search-from-modify-html-output?rq=1 should give you a starting point

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the thing is that If I place `$output = '<div></div>'; return $output` I get the same previous output... any thoughts?

Comment: You dont return output from the alter function implementation. You need to change values in the referenced variables provided instead. Eg $form['item']=array('#markup'=>'<h1>Huuhaa</h1>');

Answer (score 2):

Just create a file `search-block-form.tpl.php` and put it inside your template folder.

Paste the following code into your file.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Displays the search form block.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - $search_form: The complete search form ready for print.
 * - $search: Associative array of search elements. Can be used to print each
 *   form element separately.
 *
 * Default elements within $search:
 * - $search['search_block_form']: Text input area wrapped in a div.
 * - $search['actions']: Rendered form buttons.
 * - $search['hidden']: Hidden form elements. Used to validate forms when
 *   submitted.
 *
 * Modules can add to the search form, so it is recommended to check for their
 * existence before printing. The default keys will always exist. To check for
 * a module-provided field, use code like this:
 * @code
 *   <?php if (isset($search['extra_field'])): ?>
 *     <div class="extra-field">
 *       <?php print $search['extra_field']; ?>
 *     </div>
 *   <?php endif; ?>
 * @endcode
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_search_block_form()
 */
?>
<input type="text" id="edit-search-block-form--2" name="search_block_form" value="" placeholder="Search..." size="15" maxlength="128" />
<input class="button" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="GO!" type="submit" />
<?php echo $search['hidden']; ?>
```

Edit the code as you wish. Just make sure to leave `echo $search['hidden'];`.

You can find the original template in `YOUR-WEBSITE/modules/search/search-clock-form.tpl.php`.

---

On a side note: Instead of using `print_r()`, install [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and use `dpm()`. It's a lot better and is not visible to visitors.

Comment: Thanks, I used this. I implemented this cool custom search menu using your technique. 
https://dev.mildronize.com/en/responsive-expanding-search-bar/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `hook_form_alter` as mentioned below.

Here is the code to be used in the theme's `template.php` file that will override Drupal's search form.

```
<?php
function theme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
      print_r($form);
  print_r($form_state); // Code here

 }
}
?>
```

Either way if you are working within your custom module. It will be used as

```
<?php
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
      print_r($form);
  print_r($form_state); // Code here

 }
}
?>
```

Hope, it will work for you!